# how to create tree whose post and in order traversal is known?

Tags: data-structures, tree

how to create a tree from following post and in order traversed path

> In-order : INFORMATION
>   POST-ORDER : INOFMAINOTR

i know that all the left side elements from R will be the left sub-tree of Root 'R' and right side elements will be the right sub tree of root R 
but i don't know how to proceed further 
can any one please help me with step by step instruction thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Locate last letter in Post-Order, let it be X; which is root.
Step 2: Locate X in In-Order. Letters left to X form left sub tree & Letters to the rught of X form right sub tree.
Step 3: Repeat step 1, 2 for each node.

All the logic becomes simple when you find step 2 for the second iteration.

Comment: Awesome, just a teensy flaw: X doesn’t have to be unique. For instance, in OP’s code there are two “N”s. I don’t see a trivial way to distinguish between multiple occurrences, short of attempting to recursively solve the sub-trees and see whether they are contradictory or not.